# Free/ cheap way to receive and send emails from @mydomain account

Tags: domains, email

I want to be able to **receive** email from a few **xxx@mydomain** email accounts and also **send** email from those addresses.

Now, I'm looking for a very, very cheap, or free alternative.

To receive my email, I thought of just using a free email forwarding service from a DNS registrar offer. Something like:

> mail_1@mydomain.com  ->  forward to freemail_1@gmail.com
>
> mail_2@mydomain.com  ->  forward to freemail_2@gmail.com

Now, how can I send emails from **mail_1@mydomain.com**?

Also, is my approach correct? Or is there a better option for free/ almost free (< 40$ for 5 email accounts)?

Answer (score 1):

If your domain registrar provides the facility to forward email addresses then you can use that to receive the email to a (free) gmail account.

Gmail can then be configured to send email from this email address in Settings > Accounts > Send mail as. You need to prove ownership of this email address by receiving email to it, which you have already set up in the first step.

However, if you don't have an SMTP server for this account through which to send mail, then you will need to use gmail's. This is OK, but it will expose the gmail account email in the `Sender:` header. Depending on the email client used to receive your email, this may or may not be visible to the recipient.

You can also use an alternative email account (which you already own) to receive email and send via another email client using your existing email's SMTP server. Or collect email from Gmail using POP3/IMAP and send via an alternative email client...?

Comment: After searching a bit more, I found this cheap alternative: [Namecheap Open-Xchange Mail](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/users/1243/w3d) (**Personal Mail** plan with 5 mails is only $5.99/ year). Very appealing. Are there any other good offers?

Comment: Sounds as good as any (that link links to my profile btw!?) and is cheap. Uptime and reliability are factors to consider, but I have nothing better to offer for the price.

Comment: Sorry. Meant to link to: http://www.namecheap.com/email/email-hosting.aspx

Comment: Thanks for the correction. If the answer answers your query then you can mark it as "accepted". (Although you need at least 15 rep pts before you can upvote.)

Answer (score 0):

you should be able to register your business' email account with googlemail. that way you can send emails from @yourdomain.com.  [link](http://support.aquesthosting.com/knowledgebase.php?action=displayarticle&id=33)
hope this helps

Comment: Although this is not free. Gmail for business is currently $50 per user (mailbox), so if you have 5 mailboxes (not simply aliases) as seems to be suggested in the question, then that's $250 (assuming you pay the yearly plan and not the flexible monthly plan).

Comment: good point. obviously didnt take the high cost into consideration before replying. forgive me